# ASK : What if 1 server send ping to 5000 or more device?

Tags: server, overloading, bandwidth, flooding

What if 1 server send  ping to 5000  or more device at same time? does it cause bandwidth overload? or does it make flooding?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would depend on your network bandwidth. But, on a regular 1GBPS lan, I don't think it would overload it.

Comment: what if its not lan?

Comment: I guess it would depend on the Network's bandwidth then.